# Make the display of selection in Many2many field into "Employee (Department)" in Odoo

Tags: odoo, widget, many-to-many, odoo-14

Any idea on how to make the value of employee_ids with {Employee ID - Department name}? So when I select on the field it should look like this: Person1 (Dept A), Person2 (Dept B)

This is my XML:

```
<field name="employee_ids" widget="many2many_tags" />
```

These are my fields:

```
employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee') 
employee_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.employee', string='Assigned to')
```

Comment: That is or was possible by overriding `name_get` of a model (here `hr.employee`) and extending the logic on when and what to build the name with. You can for example use the `context` to change the name bullding on every occasion. An example in Odoo itself is in model `res.partner` in module `base`. There is a context flag `show_address` which appends the whole address to the partner name. This feature is used in for example sales orders (module `sale`).